# Сравнение 2х очень похожих изображений

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытался сравнивать с помощью imagehash, но в случае с некоторыми похожими изображениями картинки были разные, а хеш почему-то один. В foundImage попадает картинка, после чего я вырезаю кусок для проверки и сравниваю с кусками которые у меня есть в папке с помощью imagehash, если куска нет то он сохраняется. Какие есть лаконичные варианты проверить 2 картинки? Перерыл интернет, не нашел толковых примеров.

```
def foundImage(img):
    img = Image.open(img)#Картинка
    area = (50, 50, 100, 100)#Параметры обрезки картинки
    cropped_img = img.crop(area)#Обрезаем картинку
    
    hash = imagehash.average_hash(cropped_img)
    for file in glob.glob('res/*.png'):
        oldHash = imagehash.average_hash(Image.open(file))
        if hash == oldHash:
            return(file)#name arena


    randomName = ''.join([random.choice(list('123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM')) for x in range(12)])
    cropped_img.save('res/' + randomName + 'greenNO.png')#Сохраняем
    
    return 0
```

Comment: "Похожесть" - понятие очень расплывчатое. Что вы имеете в виду под "похожестью" в данном случае?

Comment: @CrazyElf черное изображение стало красным, и при сравнении красного с черным оно решает что hash == oldHash true.

Comment: А что за функция считает хэш - ваша или какая-то библиотечная? Надо посмотреть. Очень странно, что у разных файлов совпадает

Comment: @CrazyElf библиотечная.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из комментария автора поста:

> черное изображение стало красным, и при сравнении красного с черным
> оно решает что hash == oldHash true.

При этом в описании библиотеки ImageHash [написано](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash):

The image hash algorithms (**average**, perception, difference, wavelet) **analyse** the image structure on **luminence (without color information)**. The **color hash** algorithm analyses the **color distribution** and black & gray fractions (without position information).

Таким образом, использованная функция `average_hash` просто игнорирует цветовые составляющие картинки, она учитывает только яркость пикселов. Если нужно учитывать именно цвет картинки, то можно использовать функцию `colorhash`, которая учитывает распределение цветовых составляющих (но не учитывает позиции пикселов).